Apps Script to add timestamp based on importfile from another sheet
I need help to add a timestamp to B2 in TIMESTAMP sheet if I imported CSV file in IMPORT FMS Sheet, I want to know when the last time my colleagues update the sheet
I'm not an expert using AppsScript but I gathered info from internet, and I managed to add basic timestamp to it
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col == 1 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "TIMESTAMP"){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2).setValue(currentDate);
  }
}

But the problem, it won't work based on Imported file, instead it works only if I edited cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet manually (typing or copy paste from certain cell in IMPORT FMS sheet)
Here is the Sample Sheet and here is the Test File that I want to import
I'm expecting if I import (File > Import then Replace Current Sheet) the TEST FILE in IMPORT FMS sheet, a timestamp will appear on B2 in TIMESTAMP sheet based on changed in cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet (cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet is linked to A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet)
So if I import another file later on, the value on A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet will also change with new value so will with cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet because it linked to A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet Thank you for your help
Here is the Sample Sheet and here is the Text File that I want to import
Thank you for your help

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand make it work if cell B2 in TIMESTAMP sheet change based on cell reference in IMPORT FMS sheet when I import file in IMPORT FMS sheet. Can I ask you about the details of when I import file in IMPORT FMS sheet?

My apologize for my poor english :(
I'm expecting if I import (File > Import) the TEST FILE in IMPORT FMS sheet, a timestamp will appear on B2 in TIMESTAMP sheet based on changed in cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet (cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet is linked to A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet) So if I import another file later on, the value on A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet will change so will with cell A2 in TIMESTAMP sheet because it linked to A2 in IMPORT FMS sheet Thank you for your help

onChange has a type which works on import I think it is other but check the event object because they may not be the same.

I'm sorry, I'm confused. The test CSV file consists of a header "LH Trip Number" plus 9 rows of data in a single column. None of the data bears any resemblance to a timestamp. The question appears to assume that cell A2 of the imported CSV file will contain a timestamp when clearly this is not the case. I do understand the wish to create a list of timestamps showing the dates that files were imported AND there are several ways of creating (,saving, and appending) a timestamp when a new CSV file is imported. Would you please explain the source of the timestamp in the CSV file.

The Sample CSV file is located on Google Drive and it is named "Test File.csv". When the system is up and running, will CSV files also be sourced from Google Drive, will they be in a given folder, will "old" files be retained, and how will new files be named? I am wondering whether the file name might incorporate the file date.
